# File not found with knitr::include_graphics in rmarkdown via RStudio when data and pdf-image present

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I use `win10` system and have the following file tree

- `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\islr`

  - `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\islr\data\Advertising.csv`
  - `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\islr\fig\2-1.pdf`

I have some **.csv data sets** and **.pdf figures** from https://www.statlearning.com/resources-first-edition; or *you can test my `demo.rmd` using any `.csv data` and `.pdf figure` available at hand*.

My `demo.rmd` reads as follows:

````
---
title: "TTT"
author: "aaa"
date: "2023"
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir=r"[C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\islr\data]")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  message = FALSE, 
  warning = FALSE,
  fig.align = "center"
)
library(knitr)
```

## data input

```{r}
ad = read.csv("Advertising.csv",row.names=1)
head(ad)
```

## image input

```{r}
getwd()
file.exists("../fig/2-1.pdf")
include_graphics('../fig/2-1.pdf')
```
````

When I test above `demo.rmd`, the **data input** part seems ok (you can test it by adding `eval=F` in the last code chunk), while the **image input** part gives error as

```
! LaTeX Error: File `../fig/2-1' not found.
```

However, commands

```
getwd()
file.exists("../fig/2-1.pdf")
```

show

```
[1] "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/islr/data"
[1] TRUE
```

which makes me very confused! Did I neglect anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the path set via `root.dir` sets the working directory for the code chunks. However, for images the root path is the path of the `Rmd`. See [The working directory for R code chunks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/working-directory.html#working-directory). One option which worked for me would be to use an absolute file path by wrapping your relative path in `normalizePath()` and setting `rel_path=FALSE`.

````
```
---
title: "TTT"
author: "aaa"
date: "2023"
output: beamer_presentation
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = r"[C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\islr\data]")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  message = FALSE, 
  warning = FALSE,
  fig.align = "center"
)
library(knitr)
```

## data input

```{r}
ad = read.csv("mtcars.csv",row.names=1)
head(ad)
```

## image input

```{r}
include_graphics(normalizePath("../fig/2-1.pdf"), rel_path = FALSE)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Tks for replying!  This time, with your `include_graphics(normalizePath("../fig/2-1.pdf"), rel_path = FALSE)` solution, the error  `! LaTeX Error: File `../fig/2-1' not found.` has gone, while new error shows `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> C:Users   xxx Desktop islr fig 2-1 l.10 ...ics{C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\islr\fig\2-1} `. I use the `keep_tex: yes` to check and find the problem of `\begin{center}\includegraphics{C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\islr\fig\2-1} \end{center}` in tex. We should manually change it to `\includegraphics{C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/islr/fig/2-1}` to work! That is weird!@stefan

Comment: Grrr. Windows. :D I ran the code on a Mac which by default uses forward slashes. But I just saw that `normalizePath` has a `winslash` argument which defaults to `"\\"`. At the moment I can't check on a Windows machine but perhaps you could try `normalizePath(..., winslash = "/")`.

Comment: I am afraid I indeed have not change the default settings in Rstudio with rmarkdown, while  I meet the new error and you can run the same code successfully! How this can happen? Maybe issues related to the versions of the R, Rstudio or packages? @stefan